# Finding postdoc in US

Tags: publications, postdocs

I am from Singapore and I am about the graduated from PhD.
My field is in software engineering, computer science.

I plan to further my study as postdoc in US, looking at my friends, it seems that although some of them have 1-2 top ranked publications in 
conference, but they are hard to secure a desired postdoc position in US.

I wish to get a postdoc position in US, hopefully in some top research labs, is there anyone has some general recommendations on how to improve one's chance in getting those labs in US?

Comment: What are your qualifications exactly and what is probably hindering you? I.e. in which fields do you lack experience?

Comment: Hi William07. Postdoc hirin' theme has been amply discussed on this website. You might find this question [http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/986/how-do-you-grow-your-own-post-doc-opportunity] and this question  [http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/73/what-are-the-most-important-criteria-to-consider-when-hiring-postdocs-for-a-rese] very interesting. G-Luck!

Comment: This topic has definitely been covered. See: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7371/what-is-the-perception-of-foreign-universities-non-uk-in-the-us-for-prospectiv and http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8274/is-one-or-two-years-postdoc-experience-helpful-for-a-nonacademic-research-car and http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/970/postdoc-opportunities-in-mathematics and http://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=postdoc+in+US